# Bayesian regression - prior dist for variables

Tags: regression, bayesian

In a multiple Bayesian linear regression model, do all variables (dependent and predictors) get prior distributions?

If so, can one mix non-informative and substantive priors in the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a multiple Bayesian linear regression model, do all variables
>   (dependent and predictors) get prior distributions?

All **parameters** get a prior. Random variables/data might get a prior if you're modeling missing/latent/hidden data.

> If so, can one mix non-informative and substantive priors in the
>   model?

Based on this information alone, I don't see anything wrong with this approach.